# How to fix foreign key's fix drop-down list selection in admin? [Django]

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use Django 1.6 with admin-sites.

I have set my `Hoge` model with a foreign key to the User model.

```
class Hoge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, verbose_name=u'User')
```

In the admin web page, it shows drop-down list of users against the foreign key, however I want this to only show the current user.

Could you tell me how to write in `admin.py`?

```
class HogeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # something
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "fix selection"? As in it defaults a certain user, of that it only shows the current user?

Comment: Hello vishen. Thank you for replying. Yes! I wanted to say that you said. I'm sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [override the `formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), like so:

```
class HogeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "user":
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
            kwargs['initial'] = request.user
        return super(HogeAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

This just alters the `user` field, and set the query set to all users with the same primary key (`pk`) as the current user (which will just be the current user), and sets the initial value to the current user.

Comment: If this answer helped you can notify other users by accepring it by clicking the green tick